# new download links are not visible to the customer

Tags: wordpress

When the product is updated in wordpress, the new download links are not visible to the customer.

1. https://prnt.sc/ruogi8
2. https://prnt.sc/ruogpj
3. https://prnt.sc/ruogvj
4. https://prnt.sc/ruoh29

What method of solution do you know to solve this?

Comment: Maybe it's cache issue. Have you tried to flush it?

Comment: No, it's not. The problem is Woocommerce But I don't know what the solution is